# Android LiveWallpaper picker crash

Tags: android, classcastexception, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create my own livewallpaper for Android. I have starting project that compiles and opens settings Activity. But after clicking button for select wallpaper picker crashes and appears following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperListAdapter$LiveWallpaperEnumerator.doInBackground(LiveWallpaperListAdapter.java:226)
    at com.android.wallpaper.livepicker.LiveWallpaperListAdapter$LiveWallpaperEnumerator.doInBackground(LiveWallpaperListAdapter.java:149)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```

It appears also if open wallpaper picker from phone settings.
Can my wallpaper be the reason of error? And how? I don't use any drawable at the moment.

**Added**

Code for open wallpaper picker:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.WALLPAPER_PREVIEW_META_DATA,
                new ComponentName(SettingsActivity.this, MyWallpaperService.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

And `MyWallpaperService` class code:

```
public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MyEngine();
    }

    private class MyEngine extends Engine {
        private boolean visible;
        private Handler handler;
        private Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                draw();
            }
        };
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private BallsContainer balls;

        public MyEngine() {
            balls = new BallsContainer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
          this.visible = visible;
          if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
          } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
          super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
          this.visible = false;
          handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
          super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        }

        private void draw() {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
              canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
              if (canvas != null) {
                  balls.Draw(canvas, width, height);
              }
            } finally {
              if (canvas != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
            if (visible) {
              handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 100);
            }
          }
    }
}
```

**Added one more time**

`BallsContainer` draw method:

```
public void Draw(Canvas canvas, int width, int height) {
    Iterator<Ball> iter = balls.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        Ball b = iter.next();
        b.Move(width, height);
        b.Draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

And `Ball` draw method:

```
public void Draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(pos.x, pos.y, radius, paint );
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 `LiveWallpaperListAdapter` is not my class - it's Androids.

Comment: Ah, see that now. Still, please add whatever code is in your AsyncTask

Comment: @cricket_007 I have no `AsyncTask`s - it is all inside Androids wallpaper picker.

Comment: Then add the code that happens when *clicking button for select wallpaper*

Comment: @cricket_007 Added to question.

Comment: And `BallContainer.Draw` method, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only advice from Phillips support was to make factory reset. I made it - there is no more crash. I don't like this solution, but it works and I haven't a better one.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` throws `ClassCastException` because it try to cast `LayerDrawable` to `BitmapDrawable`. Provide Drawable instance that can be cast to BitmapDrawable safely.